# Testing two way dependent classes in TDD

Tags: tdd

Recently I wanted to learn TDD by developing a real thing, so I decided to go with simple data packer/unpacker. After design on paper everything looked good, but when I attempted to code it I realised I don't know how to test it, so in TDD - how to do anything.

I have two classes: `ArchiveReader` and `ArchiveWriter`. Problem is, when I save something to file with `ArchiveWriter` I can't test it properly without `ArchiveReader`, without it I am forced to compare output byte by byte and I think that's not good idea - minor, urrelevant changes can occur later. `ArchiveReader` tests also needs something to read, so I have to use `ArchiveWriter` to make test packages.

Is TDD failing in this area? Is there any method to test cases like this?

Comment: If I was testing something that read or wrote out some bytes, I would want to check that it was byte-for-byte perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have the code for the two classes then it's not really TDD, because *tests* did not *drive* the *design*.

You can still test your code, depending on how the dependencies of those classes are handled.  For example, if the `ArchiveWriter` class writes to a stream, you can have it output to a memory stream instead of a file stream, the writer should not care what kind of stream it is, and it will allow you to compare the results of the write method.

Same goes for the `ArchiveReader` class, if it reads from a stream, then it can be a memory stream.

As for your question about `ArchiveWriter` and `ArchiveReader` are mutually dependent on verifying each other, I don't think this is necessarily a problem.  While it would be ideal to be able to test both on their own, isolated, there is no rule that a unit-test can only test a single class.

As for these classes, in production, they are likely always to be used in tangent with each other, writing an archive is pointless if you cannot read it again later.

Comment: Even without code in place it sounds like the interface for these classes was determined before writing the test so there is still no room for the experience of writing the test to inform that design. If you instead set out to write a test that verified the behavior of reading and writing an archive would you end up with these two classes or a different (potentially better) interface?

Comment: I haven't done any code yet. Maybe I am missing a point, but I don't see any difference between checking stream content and file content, difficulty is in my opinion equal - it's still like byte by byte operation. Are you suggesting this path? Then what to do with little changes of design which happens somethimes, additional fields in header etc. Modyfying tests to meet requirements? I thought that in TDD it's only about adding tests neither removing nor modyfing them.

Comment: In tests you try and have one logical assertion, (for `ArchiveWriter`) a test could be that the result has the correct headers, another test could be that the correct metadata, another test could be that it has the correct filenames in the archive, another could be that the archive has a md5 hash inside for verification, etc.  If you can think of 10 different things that you need to assert about the code, then it wouldn't be unreasonable to have 10 or more tests.  In fact, you may have many more for testing non-success scenarios.  Make your tests specific, and write degenerate cases first.

Comment: @gecio The difference between stream vs. file is that tests for the latter requires a physical file location, coupling that which is abstract (your `ArchiveReader` and `ArchiveWriter`) to that which is concrete (file system). Tests like these are brittle; just because it can write to a particular location on your file system doesn't imply it can do so on others'. Using memory stream liberates your tests from these kind of coupling.

Comment: @gecio Also, TDD is **not** just about adding tests. Tests are modified and removed as per changes to requirements, which may render the tests incorrect, obsolete or irrelevant. Of course, one can't `@ignore` tests just because they get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

I develop this kind of code, which has two classes or methods that must read and write the same binary format, using TDD all the time.

You mentioned checking the output byte by byte. I prefer the analogous tests of the input code, as although I must hand craft the binary inputs, the behaviour of the input code is generally much easier to check. It will delegate to methods or create objects, which you can check it does correctly in the usual way.

I also have *symmetry tests*. These use the output code to create the binary representation, then have the input code create a new set of objects from that binary representation. The tests check that the original and new objects are equivalent. These tests are easy to write and produce useful duagnostics when they fail.

Now, some people would say, oh, but you are not doing unit testing, because your symmetry tests test both the output code and the input code; you are doing *integration tests* and therefore *doing it wrong*. This should not worry you. The idea that there is a neat division between unit and integration tests, and that everything must be tested by unit tests before having integration tests is wrong. In practice, almost no code is tested in perfect isolation; most tested code uses other classes, even if they are such basics as `String` and `HashMap`. It is more useful to view tests as being on a continuum between perfect unit tests and perfect integration tests, to prefer all code to have tests near the unit test end, but not to get too worried if some code does not do so.

Answer (score 1):

TDD is almost about **unit testing**. Unit testing is about testing of fully isolated independent unit of work. Simply, it is about testing of some logic of some your public method with all dependencies and environment to be faked.

In your example it means that if you want to unit test ArchiveReader or ArchiveWriter, at first you should isolate it from real I/O and test just logic (C#/java/... "your code").

If you are testing your application in a complex way, it is mostly about integration testing. And thus your assertions is needed to be against files your ArchiveWriter produce.

Before going to TDD, I recommend you to read at least one good book about just unit testing. Roy Osherove's book is perfect for me.